# Error trying to compile cardano-node on Raspberry Pi

Tags: cardano-node

I tried to compile the cardano-node 1.27.0 for Raspberry PI4 following the instructions and everything gets well until I do the:

```
cabal build all
```

Then all compiles until I get this error:

```
   src/Testnet/Byron.hs:71:20: error: [-Woverflowed-literals, -Werror=overflowed-literals]
    Literal 8000000000000000 is out of the Int range -2147483648..2147483647
   |
71 |   , totalBalance = 8000000000000000
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

<no location info>: error: [-Wunused-packages, -Werror=unused-packages]
    The following packages were specified via -package or -package-id flags,
    but were not needed for compilation:
      - ansi-terminal-0.11
```

Can someone tell me why is this? Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Cardano stack exchange! Can you please provide a bit more information? What instructions did you follow (link)? And how did you make sure you use the the correct version of the source code?

Comment: Is your Pi possibly running a 32 bit OS?

Comment: Oh, thanks! I looked with uname -m and it says armv7l su 32bits. I will download a 64bits os image and try again and update the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [this](https://tdiesler.gitbook.io/cardano/v/iohk/plain-docker/raspberrypi-4). It shows how to setup the Pi4 to build cardano-node, but you could also simply run the cardano-node in docker.

Comment: Welcome to our community! Unfortunately this is a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/391772) unless you summarize what that link tells us in terms of showing how to setup the Pi4. This type of answer is best left as a comment, which unfortunately you won't be able to do without earning a bit of reputation by writing high-quality (much longer) answers.